# how to configure Google Cloud Platform Data Loss Prevention client library for python to work behind a SSL proxy?

Tags: python, ssl, google-cloud-platform, proxy, google-cloud-dlp

I am trying to have Google Cloud Platform Data Loss Prevention (DLP) client library for python working behind a SSL proxy:
https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/libraries#client-libraries-usage-python

I am using the code snippet from the doc:

```
# Import the client library
import google.cloud.dlp
import os
import subprocess
import json
import requests
import getpass
import urllib.parse

import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

# Instantiate a client.
dlp_client = google.cloud.dlp.DlpServiceClient()

# The string to inspect
content = 'Robert Frost'

# Construct the item to inspect.
item = {'value': content}

# The info types to search for in the content. Required.
info_types = [{'name': 'FIRST_NAME'}, {'name': 'LAST_NAME'}]

# The minimum likelihood to constitute a match. Optional.
min_likelihood = 'LIKELIHOOD_UNSPECIFIED'

# The maximum number of findings to report (0 = server maximum). Optional.
max_findings = 0

# Whether to include the matching string in the results. Optional.
include_quote = True

# Construct the configuration dictionary. Keys which are None may
# optionally be omitted entirely.
inspect_config = {
    'info_types': info_types,
    'min_likelihood': min_likelihood,
    'include_quote': include_quote,
    'limits': {'max_findings_per_request': max_findings},
}

# Convert the project id into a full resource id.
parent = dlp_client.project_path('my-project-id')

# Call the API.
response = dlp_client.inspect_content(parent, inspect_config, item)

# Print out the results.
if response.result.findings:
    for finding in response.result.findings:
        try:
            print('Quote: {}'.format(finding.quote))
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        print('Info type: {}'.format(finding.info_type.name))
        # Convert likelihood value to string respresentation.
        likelihood = (google.cloud.dlp.types.Finding.DESCRIPTOR
                      .fields_by_name['likelihood']
                      .enum_type.values_by_number[finding.likelihood]
                      .name)
        print('Likelihood: {}'.format(likelihood))
else:
    print('No findings.')
```

I also setup the following ENV variable:

```
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
```

It run without issue when U am not behind a SSL proxy. When I am working behind a proxy, I am setting up the 3 ENV variables:

```
REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE
HTTP_PROXY
HTTPS_PROXY
```

With such setup other GCP Client python libraries works fine behind a SSL proxy as for example for storage or bigquery).

For the DLP Client python lib, I am getting:

```
E0920 12:21:49.931000000 24852 src/core/tsi/ssl_transport_security.cc:1229] Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed.
DEBUG:google.api_core.retry:Retrying due to 503 Connect Failed, sleeping 0.0s ...
E0920 12:21:50.927000000 24852 src/core/tsi/ssl_transport_security.cc:1229] Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed.
DEBUG:google.api_core.retry:Retrying due to 503 Connect Failed, sleeping 0.0s ...
```

I didn't find in the documentation explaining if the lib works with proxy as the one GCP client lib and how to configure it to works with SSL proxy. The lib is in beta so it could be that it is not yet implemented.

It seems related to CA certificate and handshake. No issue with the same CA for BigQuery and Storage Client python lib. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summary:

1. Data Loss Prevention Client libray for python use gRCP.
   google-cloud-dlp use gRPC while google-cloud-bigquery and
   google-cloud-storage rely on the requests library for
   JSON-over-HTTPS. Because it is gRPC other env variable need to be
   setup:

   ```
   GRPC_DEFAULT_SSL_ROOTS_FILE_PATH=path_file.pem  
   # for debugging
   RPC_TRACE=transport_security,tsi  
   GRPC_VERBOSITY=DEBUG
   ```

   More details and links can be found here [link](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/9276)
2. This doesn't solve all the issues because it continue to fail after
   the handsake (TLS proxy) as described here [link](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/5591). As well
   explained by @John Hanley we should enable Private Google Access
   instead which is the recommended and secure way. This is not yet in
   place in the network zone I am using the APIs so the proxy team
   added a SSL bypass and it is now working. I am waiting to have Private Google Access enbale to have a clean and secure setup to use GCP APIs.

Answer (score 1):

Your proxy is performing `TLS Interception`. This results in the Google libraries not trusting the SSL certificate that your proxy is presenting when accessing Google API endpoints. This is a man-in-the-middle problem.

The solution is to bypass the proxy for Google APIs. In your VPC subnet where your application is running, enable Private Google Access. This requires that the default VPC routing rule still exists (or recreate it).

[Private Google Access](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/private-access-options#pga)

[EDIT after comments below]

**I am adding this comment to scare the beeswax out of management.**

TLS Interception is so dangerous that no reasonable company would implement it if they read the following.

The scenario in this example. I am an IT person responsible for a corporate proxy. The company has implemented TLS Interception and I control the proxy. I have no access to Google Cloud resources for my company. I am very smart and I understand Google Cloud IAM and OAuth very well. I am going to hack my company because maybe I did not get a raise (invent your own reason).

I wait for one of the managers who has an organization or project owner/editor level permissions to authenticate with Google Cloud. My proxy logs the HTTPS headers, body and response for everything going to `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token` and a few more URLs.

Maybe the proxy is storing the logs on a Google Cloud Bucket or a SAN volume without solid authorization implemented. Maybe I am just a software engineer that finds the proxy log files laying about or easily accessed.

The corporate admin logs into his Google Account. I capture the returned OAuth Access Token. I can now impersonate the org admin for the next 3,600 seconds. Additionally, I capture the OAuth Refresh Token. I can now recreate OAuth Access Tokens at my will anytime I want until the Refresh Token is revoked which for most companies, they never do.

For doubters, study my Golang project which shows how to save OAuth Access Tokens and Refresh Tokens to a file for any Google Account used to authenticate. I can take this file home and be authorized without any authentication. This code will recreate the Access Token when it expires giving me almost forever access to any account these credentials are authorized for. Your internal IT resources will never know that I am doing this outside of your corporate network.

Note: Stackdriver Audit logging can capture the IP address, however, the identity will be the credentials that I stole. To hide my IP address, I would go to Starbucks or a public library a few hours drive from my home/job and do my deeds from there. Now figure out the where and the who for this hacker. This will give a forensics expert heartburn.

https://github.com/jhanley-com/google-cloud-shell-cli-go

Note: This problem is not an issue with Google OAuth or Google Cloud. This is an example of a security problem that the company has deployed (TLS Interceptions). This style of technique will work for almost all authentication systems that I know of that do not use MFA.

[END EDIT]

Comment: why is it working fine for BigQuery and Storage Client libraries ? In these case I had to path CA certificates and proxy info in the env variables.  Unfortunately concerning your suggestion, the default VPC routing was removed for compliance reason. I will try to disable the the handshake to see what happen.

Comment: I am not sure as I have not tried to analyze the Google libraries for TLS interception. I will say that what you are trying to do is a problem for Google libraries and I don't think Google supports TLS interception. The fact that it works for BigQuery and Storage indicates a bug (from a security standpoint) that you might find corrected in the future once Google reads this thread.

Comment: One possible reason for BigQuery and Cloud Storage working is that their libraries use HTTP for the transport. This was the case in early 2018 and I need to confirm that this is still the case today. If you look at your proxy logs, you will be able to determine which protocol (HTTP or HTTPS) the client library is using.

Comment: I am not a proxy expert. I believe some Google libraries are working fine with "TLS Interception" if you provide the needed  proxy info and CA certificate file. For example, If drop "REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE" then both BigQuery and Storage GCP client libraries are failing with:
"TransportError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='oauth2.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /token (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),))"
as expected. Maybe I didn't understand you well.

Comment: @Dr.FabienTarrade - I have not spent the time to research TLS interception with Google Cloud API libraries. I am very experienced in security and I could create all kinds of problems and steal credentials, data, etc in a network where TLS Interception is allowed. This is where man-in-the-middle attacks come from. I would not, let me repeat, I would not connect to a network that used Proxy TLS interception and required me to install a certificate bundle on my computer.

Comment: Thanks for you comments. I need to digest them since I am not a proxy expert. 
What I just learned from the DLP team:
Neither google-cloud-bigquery nor google-cloud-storage use gRPC: instead, they rely on the requests library for JSON-over-HTTPS. DLP use gRPC and things need to be setup differently.

Comment: @Dr.FabienTarrade - Thank you for the update. I do a lot of work with gRPC as many Google APIs use them. I have not done any testing of gRPC and proxies. Given the DLP's primary goal is to process and detect sensitive information, using an Intercept Proxy is really going to be a problem for you from both a security and implementation viewpoint.